# Unable to install automake1.9

Tags: debian, debian-jessie

I am not able to install automake1.9 on Debian 8. While running `apt-get install automake1.9` I am getting `Unable to locate package automake1.9` error.

I have tried updating repo list but that also did not help

Output of **apt-get install automake1.9**

```
root@serv1:~# apt-get install automake1.9
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package automake1.9
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'automake1.9'
root@serv1:~#
```

**Content in sources.list**
    # deb http://mirrors.linode.com/debian/ jessie main

```
deb http://mirrors.linode.com/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/debian/ jessie main

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://mirrors.linode.com/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/debian/ jessie-updates main

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

I have tried all possible option by changing repo list and also searching on google but did not find any solution.

Do I need to add or update anything in the sources.list file or install it manually?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to install such an ancient version of automake? Are you following a bad tutorial?

[This old version of automake](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=automake1.9) was removed from Debian and last appeared in Debian wheezy.

You probably need to be using a *current* version of automake instead. At least, you need to be viewing whatever instructions you were following with a great deal of skepticism.